# Why github action workflow run twice on first push to my repository?

Tags: github-actions

Github action workflow run twice on first push to my repository.

I added this workflow to my laravel project,here is my workflow

```
name: Deployment Workflow
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: List all files
        run: ls -la
```

I create github repository and then push the project to main branch for the first time,the workflow triggers twice.

[image]

But in the next pushes,the workflow trigger just once

[image]

Can someone explain why the workflow runs twice on first commit(first push)?

Comment: Your workflow looks fine. Most probably, this could be due to the outage (https://www.githubstatus.com/). Seems like it's back to normal. You may try again and verify.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially a bug with GitHub actions, see:
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50356